# How do I navigate many to many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Simplifying the question:

I have 3 tables: Person, PersonCreditCard, CreditCard. 
A person has many credit card and a credit card belongs to many people (yes, my wife can use my credit card :) )
I used Code First to generate the class:

```
public  class Person
    {
        public Person()
        { PersonCreditCard = new HashSet<PersonCreditCard>(); }
        [Key]
        public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonCreditCard> PersonCreditCard { get; set; }
}



public partial class PersonCreditCard
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CreditCardID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }
}


public partial class CreditCard
{
    public CreditCard()
    { PersonCreditCard = new HashSet<PersonCreditCard>(); }

    public int CreditCardID { get; set; }
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonCreditCard> PersonCreditCard { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to display the count of person by type of credit card. In SQL, it is easy:

```
select count(p.BusinessEntityID), cc.CardType
from Person.Person p
join Sales.PersonCreditCard pcc
on p.BusinessEntityID = pcc.BusinessEntityID
join Sales.CreditCard cc
on cc.CreditCardID = pcc.CreditCardID
group by cc.CardType
```

But in Linq to SQL, I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Can you show code that defines your entities? Specially, BusinessEntityAddress

Comment: it is generated directly from adventureworks

Comment: if you want to see the full erd:  https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC4QFjACahUKEwixj4-0ppXJAhXBlx4KHUsjBac&url=https%3A%2F%2Fakela.mendelu.cz%2F~jprich%2Fvyuka%2Fdb2%2FAdventureWorks2008_db_diagram.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHkbsh5BustELHF69mabsC82O40Qw

Comment: are those two different databases?

Comment: no, this is MS demo database. The ERD is for the 2008 version, and I'm using 2014, but this part of the database didn't changed.

Comment: So `where p.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityAddress.AddressType.Name = "Home"` does not work for you?

Comment: yes it works in tsql. I want to replicate it in linq. The problem is how to write the where in linq.

Comment: I changed the example because it was too complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

```
var query = from p in c.Person
            from pcc in p.PersonCreditCard
            group p by new { pcc.CreditCard.CardType } into g
            select new
            {
                cname = g.Key.CardType,
                cptPerson = g.Count()
            };
```

the trick is to see that a from in linq is not a from in SQL. It "kind of" return a collection. So to go on the other side of the PersonCreditCard collection, I need another from to define a var that I can use to jump over the other side of that collection.

Anybody could point me to a good (real) description of this behaviour. I would like to understand it with the real terminology (I'm a teacher, and I will have to explain this to my students in a few weeks ;)

thanks

Comment: see my follow up on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192508/entity-framework-multiple-from-is-generating-cross-join