# Entity Framework: multiple from is generating cross join

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to Entity Framework and I was working on a query and found a solution, but after some investigation with LINQPad, I don't like the resulting SQL.

The Linq query is:

```
from p in Person
from pcc in p.PersonCreditCard
group p by new { pcc.CreditCard.CardType } into g
select new
{
     cname = g.Key.CardType,
     cptPerson = g.Count()
}
```

The resulting sql query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [cptPerson], [t2].[CardType] AS [cname]
FROM [Person].[Person] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [Sales].[PersonCreditCard] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Sales].[CreditCard] AS [t2] ON [t2].[CreditCardID] = [t1].[CreditCardID]
WHERE [t1].[BusinessEntityID] = [t0].[BusinessEntityID]
GROUP BY [t2].[CardType
```

Notice the CROSS JOIN. 
From what I know, it is not a good idea to use a CROSS JOIN. 
Why is it doing so?

And is there another syntax I could use to get the same result (counting the number of person by credit card type)

Comment: It would be useful if you included the model for Person and PersonCreditCard. I imagine this is probably a 1 to many relationship but I don't like to assume. If it is then your mapping is probably off which would definitely explain it because EF does not know how these 2 entities are related in the DB Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting your query by `PersonCreditCard`:

```
var query= context.PersonCreditCard.GroupBy(c=>c.CreditCard.CardType)
                                   .Select(g=>new {
                                                    cname = g.Key,
                                                    cptPerson = g.Count()
                                                  }
                                          );
```

### Update

I guess in `PersonCreditCard` entity you also have a reference to a `Person`, so you can add a `Where` call to your query like this:

```
var query= context.PersonCreditCard.Where(pc=>pc.Person.Name=="John")
                                   .GroupBy(c=>c.CreditCard.CardType)
                                   .Select(g=>new {
                                                    cname = g.Key,
                                                    cptPerson = g.Count()
                                                  }
                                          );
```

### Update 2

I think I get your point, if you want to include in the result the people that belong to each group, you can do the following:

```
var query= context.PersonCreditCard.Where(pc=>pc.Person.Name=="John")
                                   .GroupBy(c=>c.CreditCard.CardType)
                                   .Select(g=>new {
                                                    cname = g.Key,
                                                    cptPerson = g.Count()
                                                    people=g.Select(pc=>pc.Person);
                                                  }
                                          );
```

Comment: yeah, it gives the right number... but it doesn't quite answer the question. You answered it by eliminating the Person table. I agree that counting the number of entries in the relation table will give the same as counting the Person... but what if I want to count the Person with firstname = John ... How would you add this to that query?

Comment: Well, my first query is based on the result that you were expecting to get using your query ;). Check my update where I added the condition that you mention in your comment

Comment: ok, I retrack what I just said. You can add a .where that is able to use Person attributes. let me think about it ... and probably you have the answer.

Comment: I have added another update, let me know if that is what you looking for.

Comment: update 2 is interesting ... but update 1 is what I was looking for (for now :) ). In update 2, I understand that it is returning the people who are counted by group. So it would be interesting to provide a list of person for each group (usefull to drill down). But it is overkill for what I want to do. Bottom line: Entity Framework is not SQL :) I will have to unlearn  most of what I know in SQL to be able to use EF.

Answer (score 0):

If you mapped your many to many relation like this

```
class Person{
 ..more properties here

  public virtual ICollection<CreditCard> CreditCards{ get; set; }
}

class CreditCard{
 ..more properties here

  public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
}
```

You can do your query like this

```
int count = _context.Persons.GroupBy(p => p.CreditCards.Select(c=>c.CardType)).Count();
```

change the _context for whatever you are using.

Comment: no, the problem is that there is a many to many relationship between Persons and CreditCard. So there is the table PersonCreditCard in between. So CardType is on CreditCard, not PersonCreditCard. And I can't do p.PersonCreditCard.CreditCard.CardType.

Comment: Do you have an entity to map that relation in your code? or you just have a list of Credits cards on the person entity and a list of person on the credit card?

Comment: The real db I'm using is AdventureWorks 2014 (MS demo db). And I used then "Entity Data Model Wizard" to import "Code First from Db". So the short answer is: yes I have an entity to map the relation between Person and CreditCard, it is called PersonCreditCard. So your answer doesn't work.